# C# Updating a dropdown box with value from another dropdown box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown box that lists authors names:

I need to have this box update with the selected value from a 2nd dropdown list.

This clears the values from the authors dropdown list but it does not update the box with the selected value from the 2nd dropdown list.  What do I need to include to get the value of the lbAuthorList to display the selected value from DroopDownList1?

```
protected void update_SelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbAuthorList.Items.Clear();
    lbAuthorList.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

}

  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lbAuthors" style="float:left;" 
    DataSourceID="odsAuthorList" DataTextField="DisplayAuthorName" DataValueField="AuthorID" 
    onselectedindexchanged="lbUserList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
      </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Display_AuthorName"  EnableViewState="false"
    DataValueField="Display_AuthorName" OnSelectedIndexChanged="update_SelectedItem" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new item to drop down list,

```
protected void update_SelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbAuthorList.Items.Clear();
    lbAuthorList.Items.Add(new ListItem(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
    lbAuthorList.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: I have now noticed that the first record from the 2nd dropdown box does not update into the first dropdown box.  How do I resolve this or is this a separate question I need to post?

Comment: Here is an example:  if I have three authors name in the 2nd dropdown box (Frost, Kipling, Poe) the first name - Frost - does not update into the first dropdown box.  Kipling or Poe do - but not Frost.  What do I need to include in my event to allow Frost (or whatever the first record is) to update into the first dropdown box?

Comment: have you try to select `Kipling` and then `Frost`? since `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event you need to change the selected item

Comment: Yes - that is the first thing I tried.  Any record I select in the 2nd dropdownbox updates to the first dropdown box EXCEPT the first record.  Is it possible to include a blank field in a dropdownbox that is populated with results from a SQLDatasource or is that just possible with hard coded listbox items?